# as2 / flash :: how to force file download via PHP

Tags: php, file, header, download, actionscript-2

I try to force a file-download via PHP with

```
$ctype="application/zip";
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath));
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");  //header("Cache-Control: public"); 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
// header("Location: $filepath"); // edited: removed
readfile($filepath);
```

but it doesn't work.

with firebug I can see the changed header information but no save-file dialog appears...

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to start the download in flash? I suspect there may be something wrong there.

Comment: I simply send some data to a PHP file which asks for some permissions in a mysql database. then the download has to start. if i tell my flash file from this php-file to call another page (_parent-window) with php-code to start the download, it works. but if I let the first php-code start the download, it doesn't work.
I think it has to be some kind of pre-send information, before the header is send, destroying the purity of my header later...

Comment: What I want to know is if you're using navigateToURL or a URLLoader. A The latter won't start a download, Flash will just eat that data regardless.

Comment: ok - I see. no, I use myData = new LoadVars() / myData.sendAndLoad() / POST

Comment: Then you must be using as2 not as3, sendAndLoad will also "eat" your response and not cause a download. You will need to use getURL()

Comment: uh, yes, seems this old file is as2! oh man, whats going on here... to much code switching! I'll try getURL. thnx!

Comment: I had to do some rearragements in my code. now it works! @grapefrukt: please write it down as answer so that I could mark it as solution. thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendAndLoad()` will "eat" your response and not cause a download which is useful if you're trying to load data. However, in your case you need to use `getURL()` since you want the browser to deal with the response, not flash.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove

```
header("Location: $filepath");
```

Which is basically redirecting you to the path specific instead of reading it's contents.

Comment: allthough your answer was kind of right, naturellemente. I've edited the question.